# Create close button for each view controller on the uinavigationcontroller stack

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to have a close button on each view controller that appears in the navigation stack. I've read [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate) that I need to create an object that is a uinavigationdelegate, I think this object will have a method like didTapCloseButton?

Questions:
Should I create a protocol and make everything confirm to it, i.e.:

```
protocol CustomDelegate: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
   func didTapCloseButton()
}

public class ViewController: CustomDelegate {
   func didTapCloseButton() {
     //not sure what goes in here?
   }
}
```

How do I get the close button to show on the navigation bars of every view?
When the user clicks the close button, how do I get that to dismiss every view on that stack?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe you might be confused here, there is actually the UINavigationControllerDelegate[1] protocol implemented by Apple.


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate

Comment: right let me edit my post so that I create a custom delegate that inherits from UINavigationDelegate.

Answer (score 5):

Here a simple solution. Create **UINavigationController** subclass and override **pushViewController** method.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

        let closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Close",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(self.popViewController(animated:)))

        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = closeBarButtonItem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you intended but you can do:

```
protocol CustomDelegate: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func didTapCloseButton()
}
extension CustomDelegate where Self : UIViewController{
    func didTapCloseButton(){
        // write your default implementation for all classes
    }

}
```

now for every `UIViewController` class you have you can just do :

```
class someViewController: CustomDelegate{

    @IBAction buttonClicked (sender: UIButton){
    didTapCloseButton()
    }
}
```